# Avoiding read-only values using a dictionary with JSON.net and Databinding

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm writing an editor for a JSON file with C# and UWP.

I have successfully gotten down to the `translations` dictionary in my JSON.

```
{
"characters": [{
    "name": "guy",
    "picture": "thing.png",
    "lines": [{
        "phrase": "hello",
        "translations": {
            "en": "Hi there, this is some text.",
            "es": ""
        }
    }]
}]
}
```

So far, everything has had consistent naming that I could easily parse - `name` will always be signified by the string `name`, so I didn't need to use a dictionary.

However, when parsing `translations`, there is any number of languages that I can support.  This means I'll need a dictionary.

Usually, my `Lines` object would contain the following:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> translations;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "translations")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Translations
    {
        get { return translations; }
        set
        {
            translations = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Translations");
        }
    }
```

This would work fine if I were just displaying data.  However, in my app, I require two-way databinding.  This means that I will have to write to the `value` of my dictionary - something that I can't do since it is `readonly`.

I have thought about using a custom object as a value of my `Dictionary`, like the following:

```
...
public Dictionary<string, Translation> Translations    
...
```

With the object

```
public class Translation
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, and JSON.net throws a parse exception - which makes sense.  JSON.net doesn't know how to convert what it thinks is a `string` to my custom `Translation` `Text` property.

Is there a tag I can use similar to `[JsonProperty]` that will allow me to use this functionality?  Thanks.

---

Just some notes - I intend to use this `.json` file with a Unity project, which means I can't use nice stuff like the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use serialization/deserialization [callbacks](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) for manual conversion:

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "translations")]
        private Dictionary<string, string> TranslationsSerialized { get; set; }

        private Dictionary<string, Translation> translations;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Dictionary<string, Translation> Translations
        {
            get { return translations; }
            set
            {
                translations = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Translations");
            }
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
        {
            Translations = TranslationsSerialized?.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => new Translation { Text = t.Value });
        }

        [OnSerializing]
        private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            TranslationsSerialized = Translations?.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value.Text);
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I knew something had to exist.  Thanks.